# Can't print string on JSP

Tags: jsp

This is my JSP code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    zerox <% System.out.println("XXX"); %>
</body>
</html>
```

when I access the file from `Tomcat` server, it prints `zerox` instead of `zerox XXX`.

Why?

Comment: Scriptlets are bad news my friend.

Comment: `System.out` prints into the debug logs, not into the response output stream... You will probably find it there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System.out.println() prints in server console, Use **zerox <%= "XXX" %>**

Comment: `<%= "XXX" %>` might work better. Your option also prints to debug logs and then tries to output the result (of type `void`) to the response output stream...